# Python if/elif issue with random.randint

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is part of a bigger problem, but I'm having some problems with this if/elif function.

```
def fish():
    import random   

    score = 0

    i = random.randint(0,39)

    if i == [0,19]:
        print("You caught nothing!")
    elif i == [20,39]:
        print("You caught a Minnow! +10 points.")
        score += 10
    print(i)
    print(score)
fish()
```

When I run this, all I get is the randint number, and 0 for the score. I'm not exactly sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with `random.randint` and nothing to do with if/elif logic; it has to do with comparing values. Think clearly about what you expect `i == [0, 19]` to mean, and why it should mean that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're comparing an integer to a list.

To do what you're trying to do, here's one way:

```
if i in range(0, 20):
    print("You caught nothing!")
elif i in range(20, 40):
    print("You caught a Minnow! +10 points.")
    score += 10
```

Answer (score 6):

Yeah, um... that's not how it works. You're comparing an integer to a list.

```
    if 0 <= i < 20:
        print("You caught nothing!")
    elif 20 <= i < 40:
        print("You caught a Minnow! +10 points.")
        score += 10
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is:

```
if i in range(20):
    print("You caught nothing!")
elif i in range(20,40):
    print("You caught a Minnow! +10 points.")
    score += 10
```

Or perhaps better:

```
if i < 20:
    print("You caught nothing!")
else:
    print("You caught a Minnow! +10 points.")
    score += 10
```

Answer (score 0):

`i` is an `int`, you're comparing an `int` with a list of `int`s, you should:

```
if i in range(19)
...
elif i in range(20,39):
```